# Laravel default auth table

Tags: php, laravel

[image]How do i change where laravel does it queries on functions like :

```
 $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);?
```

It always does it queries on the table 'users' which is a laravel default table that I don't use

Comment: `$request->validate()` has nothing to do with `users` table

Comment: could u please elaborate further on your problem?

Comment: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'accounting.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = 'example@yahoo.com')

Comment: My guess is that the validate method is making validations in the default users table but since its not present, its giving me an error. The email is specified to be unique and I'm inserting a new value.

Comment: provide your exception trace. Maybe a screenshot

Comment: Edited the question to include a screenshot

Comment: What did you try to do, when did this occur?

Comment: I removed the users table since i don't use it and added that validation. Email is specified to be unique so it's always checking that default table which is the problem. I need to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It make the query on the users table because when you use the `unique` validation rule you can pass the name of the table on which eloquent must search for the input value which is being validate.

```
$request->validate([
    'username' => 'required|string',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|string'
]);?
```

Your validation rule for `email` will search for the existance of the given `email` in the `users` table because it's the name of table which you pass as the first argument of `unique`. You can change it.

The `unique` rule take parameters like this `unique:table_name:column_name`